# Entity framework cannot read new data until request end

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I create new entitiy

```
    public int RegisterUser(string userName, string password)
    {
        var model = new User();

        model.UserName = userName;

        var salt = this.saltProvider.StringSalt();
        model.Salt = salt;

        model.Password = this.encryptionSerivce.Hash(password, options => options.WithStringSalt(salt));

        this.ValidateUser(model);

        this.users.Create(model);
        this.users.Save();

        return model.UserId;
    }
```

Where this.users.Create looks like:

```
    public void Create(T entity)
    {
        this.dbSet.Add(entity);
    }
```

And Save:

```
    public void Save()
    {
        this.dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

My problem: after call `Save()` changes are still in Local property:
[image: Debug]

So, when when I try to get just added entity (like `this.users.Fetch(usr => usr.UserName == "Just added user name")` **I'm getting null.**

My fetch looks like:

```
    public IEnumerable<T> Fetch(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return this.dbSet.Where(predicate);
    }
```

What's ridiculous, after the request's end, data are placed into db: 
[image: db result]

**I'm able to access int in next request. What I'm doing wrong?**

Why I can't access newly-added entites just after calling SaveChanges() on DbContext?

Comment: haven't you opened transaction before calling `RegisterUser` ?, after save changes, is there your record on `db`?

Comment: why you get record from db after save , while you do not need , because you have entity.

Comment: Is it possible you are working in different contexts?

Comment: Transaction is not opened, there is no record in db after save. I'd like to perform complex query to whole table and currently new record is not included into results. I don't want to get all entities, add new entity and perform server-side query instead of DB side.

Comment: Hm... I'm using autofac for injecting dbcontext and it's set to InstancePerApiRequest. Anyway I think it's the same instance but I'll make sure in few minutes.

Comment: I'm using the same instance od dbcontext.

Answer (score 0):

Because what `SaveChanges()` does is to save changes to your database and **discard** the changes to the `Dbcontext`.

That's why when you do `this.dbSet.Where(predicate)` in the **same** request, you don't get the object you just save. Until you query the DB again with a fresh new `Dbcontext`,

If you do `SaveChanges(false)`, you can achieve what you need, saving the changes while keep it in the same request.

Comment: Hmm.. I'll check that. But sounds promissing!

Comment: Unfortunately, SaveChanges is parameterless. (EF 6).